# Is the formula an absolute theorem schema?

Tags: predicate-logic

Is $ (\forall x)(A \rightarrow B) \vdash (\forall x)A \rightarrow (\forall x)B $ an absolute theorem schema ?

- If you think yes, then give a proof.
- If you think no, construct a counter model or prove the invalid strong generalization from it.

How can I do this one ?

Answer (score 1):

The inference is valid; here is a proof with *Natural Deduction* :

1) $(∀x)(A \rightarrow B)$ --- premise

2) $(∀x)A$ --- assumed [a]

3) $A \rightarrow B$ --- from 1) by $\forall$-elimination

4) $A$ --- from 2) by $\forall$-elimination

5) $B$ --- from 4) and 3) by $\rightarrow$-elimination

6) $\forall x B$ --- from 5) by $\forall$-introduction

7) $(∀x)A \rightarrow (∀x)B$ --- from 2) and 6) by $\rightarrow$-introduction, discharging assumption [a]

Thus, from 1) and 7) we have :

> $(∀x)(A \rightarrow B) \vdash (∀x)A \rightarrow (∀x)B$.